# Как подружить OpenCart 3 и VUE.js

Tags: vue.js, opencart

Дело в том, что у Opencart3 за вывод переменной в шаблоне .twig отвечает директива {{}}. В VUE за вывод переменной также отвечает директива {{}}. В итоге, при подключении в twig-шаблон VUE ничего не выводится

шаблон twig:

```
 <section id="app">
   <p v-on:click="delBr">{{ age }}</p>
 </section>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {age:25},
    methods: {
        delBr: function(){
            var width = document.body.clientWidth;
            if(width < 992)
                console.log(width)
        }                
})
</script>
```

Функция delBr работает

Comment: Можно увидеть ваш код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать так называемые [разделители](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters). Пример:

```
new Vue({
 delimiters: ['${', '}']
})

// Разделители изменены на стиль строк-шаблонов в ES6
```

Или если вы не хотите изменять разделители `Vue` - вы можете [кастомизировать разделители](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax) в `Twig`

```
$app->before(function() use ($app){
    $app['twig']->setLexer( new Twig_Lexer($app['twig'], [
        'tag_comment'   => ['[#', '#]'],
        'tag_block'     => ['[%', '%]'],
        'tag_variable'  => ['[[', ']]'],
        'interpolation' => ['#[', ']'],
    ]));
});
```

Comment: спасибо, отличное решение!